# Review Simple Logparser

Tags: python, beginner, parsing, logging

This is my first try with Python. I wanted to parse some `Log4J` so I thought it a good opportunity to write my first Python program.

The format of the logs I deal with are simply like `[INFO BLA 08:00:00] Blabla`. Most of the time there are single lines  like the above; but sometimes, there is a stack trace logged, so a logical "line" is longer than a physical line. Each "logical" line starts with the character `[`.

So I came up with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from collections import namedtuple

Logline = namedtuple("Logline", "level timestamp message")

def apply_filter(current_log_line, filtered_lines):
    parsed_line = parse_line(current_log_line)
    if filter(parsed_line):
        filtered_lines.append(parsed_line)

def get_filtered_lines(source):
    filtered_lines = []
    line_buffer = ""
    for line in source:
        if line.startswith('[') and line_buffer:
            apply_filter(line_buffer, filtered_lines)
            line_buffer = ""
        line_buffer += line
    apply_filter(line_buffer, filtered_lines)
    return filtered_lines

def parse_line(log_line):
    prefix, message = log_line.split("]", 1)
    level, timestamp = parse_prefix(prefix)
    return Logline(level, timestamp, message)

def parse_prefix(prefix):
    prefix = prefix.strip("[]")
    tokens = prefix.split(" ")
    level = tokens[0]
    timestamp = tokens[-1]
    return level, timestamp

def filter(log_line):
    return log_line.level == "ERROR" and log_line.timestamp > "07:00:00"

def console_out(lines):
    for line in lines:
        print("{}{}".format(line.timestamp, line.message.rstrip("\n")))

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: {0} $logfile".format(sys.argv[0]))
    else:
        file_name = sys.argv[1]
        with open(file_name) as file:
            console_out(get_filtered_lines(file))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Feel free to comment.

One thing, what bugs me is the `apply_filter` function, which does too many things at once. But I have have no solution for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see if I understand what's going on with get_filtered_lines() and apply_filter(). First, get_filtered_lines() reads physical lines from the file and strings them together in line_buffer. When we find the beginning of the next logical line ('['), we pass line_buffer off to apply_filter() so the material that has been collected gets processed. Then we empty out line_buffer and start over with the beginning of the logical line just read.

Here's an approach I think is simpler and clearer:

```
def apply_filter(lbuf):
    parsed = parse_line(lbuf)
    if filter(parsed):
        return [parsed]
    else
        return []

def get_filtered_lines(source):
    filtered_lines = []
    collected = ""
    for line in source:
        if line.startswith('[') and collected:
            filtered_lines.extend(apply_filter(collected))
            collected = ""
        collected += line
    filtered_lines.extend(apply_filter(collected))
    return filtered_lines
```

That way, apply_filter doesn't have to be aware of the list being built. It just returns a list of what it finds -- either a line that passes the filter or an empty list. Passing an empty list to extend is a no-op.